# "Setting unknown property" error when adding properties to instantiated object - yii2

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, yii2

I'm using yii2 and I wanted to add some extra attributes and validation rules for them to the model after I call $model->createValidators().

But when I tried with the below code, at the line "$this->{$attr->code} = null", it's throwing the error: "Setting unknown property".

```
public function rules(){
    $rules = [];
    if(!is_null($this->attributeSetId)){ // set the rules for custom attributes
        foreach($this->attributeSet->attributeGroups as $group){
            foreach($group->productAttributes as $attr){  
                if($attr->required=="1")
                    $rules[] = [[$attr->code], 'required'];
                else
                    $rules[] = [[$attr->code], 'safe'];
                $this->{$attr->code} = null; // trying to set new property to the model (this is the line causing error)
            }
        }

    }
    return array_merge([
        [['attributeSetId', 'parent', 'typeId'], 'integer'],
        [['attributeSetId'], 'required'],
    ], $rules);
}
```

I know properties can be declared to an object after we instantiate it using the above method but it's not working in the above mentioned case.

When I manually set the properties as:
    "public $propertyName;"
at the starting of the model, it's working perfect but in my case, the properties list is dynamic.

Can someone throw some light on this please?

Edit:

Comment: Maybe it's better to use conditional validation with `when`? Could your provide examples of these custom attributes.

Comment: My case is, I have the Products table and product's custom attributes on another table(similar to the case in magento). So on the create/update form, these attributes too needs to be validated via model rules. Model scenairo can't be used in this case as the attributes list is dynamic and can change any time.

Comment: Did you declare these attributes in your product model ??

Comment: Please read my comment above. The attributes are dynamic and hence can't declare them in the model.

Comment: Then nothing strange in this error... You could simply create a behavior to handle this, or override setter/getter.

Comment: Fixed this by modifying the attributes method to return the custom attributes too.